# Work dimension for arbitrary prime number of work items

Tags: opencl

I have seen many tutorials about configuring work dimensions, in which the number of work items conveniently easy to divide into 3 dimensions. I have a big number of work items, speak `164052`. What is the best way to configure arbitrary number of work items ? Since in my programm the number of work items might vary, i need a way to calculate it automatically.

What should I do when the number is prime, say  `7879` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, by default you should only be using 1 dimension for your kernels. Some tasks require 2 or 3 dimensions (generally, image processing), but unless you are expressly working on one of those tasks, it probably doesn't benefit you to try to divide stuff up among multiple dimensions, since the benefits are largely about code organization, not about performance.

So that leaves the question of how to divide up work items among local groups. Given a task size of `N` work items, you have a few options for dividing them up into local groups.

The simplest solution is to simply specify `N` work items, and let the driver decide for you how to divide those work items among the groups.

```
size_t work_items = 164052;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, nullptr, &work_items, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

If you're programming for a specific environment where you know in advance the ideal number of local work items (often 32 or 64 for NVidia/AMD architectures), you might get better performance by forcing your work item count to align to a multiple of that number.

```
size_t work_items = 164052;
size_t LOCAL_SIZE = 64;
work_items += LOCAL_SIZE - (work_items % LOCAL_SIZE);
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, nullptr, &work_items, &LOCAL_SIZE, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Note, however, that this requires that you add a check to your kernel code to prevent processing on work items that don't actually exist, or that you pad your buffers to include space for the dummy items.

```
kernel void main(..., int N) {
    if(get_global_id(0) >= N) return;
    ...
}
```